# How to refactor switch-cases so that I can extend those cases and add another case in a different class?

Tags: java

I have this chain of switch-cases

```
switch(something){
   case Case1:
      validate();
      doSomething1();
      break;
   case Case2:
      validate();
      doSomething2();
      break;
   case Case3:
      validate();
      doSomething3();
      break;
   case Case4:
      validate();
      doSomething4();
      break;
   case Case5:
      validate();
      doSomething5();
      break;
   default:
      handleDefault();
}
```

Now in a different place I want these exact switch-cases and default code but I need to add one extra case. What would be a nice way to achieve this so that I don't just have to duplicate all these cases in a different place.

Comment: Is it perhaps time to implement a different pattern? How about using objects that implement a common API method using the logic in your `doSomethingN()` methods based on `something`? That way, you avoid the switch altogether, and your `default` clause would be just an `else` block somewhere?

Comment: Are the fallthroughs intentional?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel my bad...didn't include the break in the question. Included now. So, no fallthrough happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you should use two functions for implementing the concept.

Let's say that we have a function called mainSwitchFunction(int case):

```
  public void mainSwitchFunction(int case){
     switch(something){
       case Case1:
       validate();
       doSomething1();
      case Case2:
       validate();
       doSomething2();
      case Case3:
       validate();
       doSomething3();
      case Case4:
       validate();
       doSomething4();
      case Case5:
       validate();
       doSomething5();
      default:
       handleDefault();
    }
  }
```

In normal situations you can use the same function just by calling it.

However, if you want to extend the switch case up to some other cases, you simply define another method let's say extensionOfSwitch(int case2).

```
   public void extensionOfSwitch(int case2){

    //call the original switch case function
    mainSwitchFunction(case2);

   //define another switch statement based on ur case condition.
    switch(case2){
      case:...
    }

    /*
     this way all the cases will be handled.
   */

  }
```

Comment: I think this is a good way to extend the cases. However, in the extensionOfSwitch() I would do like this `switch(case2) -> handle it;  default -> mainSwitchFunction()`.

Answer (score 0):

in my opinion, it will be better to use map for this.
something like this:

```
public class SwithCaseProblem {

    Map<Object, MyHandler> handlers = new HashMap<>();

    MyHandler myHandler = new MyHandler() { // or use lambda
        @Override
        public void doSomething() {
            // default
        };
    };

    public void perform(Object something) {
        handlers.getOrDefault(something, myHandler).doSomething();
    }

    public Map<Object, MyHandler> getHandlers() {
        return handlers;
    }

    public void setHandlers(Map<Object, MyHandler> handlers) {
        this.handlers = handlers;
    }

    private interface MyHandler { // or instead of own interface, use Runnable, Supplier, Consumer, ... what you need
        public void doSomething();
    }

}
```

Now you need only add new handler to map to extend the behavior

Comment: I didn't understand this example. Can you explain how it can be useful in this case?

Comment: The idea of this is to use handlers instead of run function in `case` statement. You get proper function from map and run it, instead of go one by other option and checking if it match and run code under the match option. You can create two `SwithCaseProblem` one will have base handlers, socond will have also additional hander.